# nil Delegate between two ViewController with two different Bundle (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, bundle

nil Delegate between two ViewController with two different Bundle using swift 4 (commented in second code)

here is my code :

**First ViewController :**

```
class FirstVC : UIViewController, MerchantResultObserver{
    var secVC = SecondVC()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        secVC.delegate = self

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: “SecondVC”, bundle: Bundle(identifier: “SecondBundle”))
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
            self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            secVC.initSecondVC(data)
    }



 func Error(data: String) {
        print("-------------Error Returned------------- \(data)")
    }


 func Response(data: String) {
        print("-------------Response Returned------------- \(data)")
    }

}
```

**Second ViewController :**

```
public class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    public weak var delegate: MerchantResultObserver!


 public func initSecondVC(_ data : String){
        print(data)
}

@IBAction func sendRequest(_ sender: UIButton) {
            delegate?.Response(data: “dataReturnedSuccessfully”)  // delegate is nil //
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)                 // returned to FirstVC without returning “dataReturnedSuccessfully” //
}

}

public protocol MerchantResultObserver: class{
    func Response(data : String)
    func Error(data : String)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var secVC = SecondVC()
```

and

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: “SecondVC”, bundle: Bundle(identifier: “SecondBundle”))
let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? SecondVC
```

These both are different instances.

You can assign a delegate to the controller, like

```
controller.delegate = self
```

It will call the implemented delegate methods in First View Controller.

Full Code.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: “SecondVC”, bundle: Bundle(identifier: “SecondBundle”))
if let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? SecondVC {
       //Assign Delegate
       controller.delegate = self

       //It's not init, but an assignment only, as per your code.
       controller.initSecondVC(data) 


      self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

One more thing, Don't present View in `ViewDidLoad`. You can put a code in some button or in a delay method.

Comment: thanks, but i got this error `Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'delegate'` And `Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'initSecondVC'`

Comment: you need to make it like

let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? SecondVC

Comment: My Pleasure. Happy Coding!